# Scikit-learn and Yellowbrick giving different scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, yellowbrick

I am using sklearn to compute the average precision and roc_auc of a classifier and yellowbrick to plot the roc_auc and precision-recall curves. The problem is that the packages give different scores in both metrics and I do not know which one is the correct.

The code used:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from yellowbrick.classifier import ROCAUC
from yellowbrick.classifier import PrecisionRecallCurve
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import average_precision_score

seed = 42

# provides de data
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000, n_features=2, n_redundant=0,
                           n_informative=2, random_state=seed)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

clf_lr = LogisticRegression(random_state=seed)
clf_lr.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = clf_lr.predict(X_test)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
avg_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
print(f"ROC_AUC: {roc_auc}")
print(f"Average_precision: {avg_precision}")
print('='*20)

# visualizations
viz3 = ROCAUC(LogisticRegression(random_state=seed))
viz3.fit(X_train, y_train) 
viz3.score(X_test, y_test)
viz3.show()
viz4 = PrecisionRecallCurve(LogisticRegression(random_state=seed))
viz4.fit(X_train, y_train)
viz4.score(X_test, y_test)
viz4.show()
```

The code produces the following output:

[image]

As it can be seen above, the metrics give different values depending the package. In the print statement are the values computed by scikit-learn whereas in the plots appear annotated the values computed by yellowbrick.

Comment: Please update your post with the exact results as given by the two packages; as is, it is not at all apparent, neither is the relevance of the graphs to the question (both of which seem to come from yellowbricks).

Comment: @desertnaut The auc score and the average precison computed by scikit-learn are in the print statement, whereas the values computed by yellowbric appear annotated in the graphs. I edit the post to clarify that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you use the `predict` method of scikit-learn, your predictions `y_pred` are hard class memberships, and not probabilities:

```
np.unique(y_pred)
# array([0, 1])
```

But for ROC and Precision-Recall calculations, this should **not** be the case; the predictions you pass to these methods should be probabilities, and not hard classes. From the `average_precision_score` [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html):

> **y_score: *array, shape = [n_samples] or [n_samples, n_classes]***
>
> Target scores, can either be probability estimates of the positive class, confidence values, or non-thresholded measure of decisions (as
> returned by “decision_function” on some classifiers).

where *non-thresholded* means exactly *not hard classes*. Similar is the case for the `roc_auc_score` ([docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html#sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score)).

Correcting this with the following code, makes the scikit-learn results identical to the ones returned by Yellowbrick:

```
y_pred = clf_lr.predict_proba(X_test)     # get probabilities
y_prob = np.array([x[1] for x in y_pred]) # keep the prob for the positive class 1
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, y_prob)
avg_precision = average_precision_score(y_test, y_prob)
print(f"ROC_AUC: {roc_auc}")
print(f"Average_precision: {avg_precision}")
```

Results:

```
ROC_AUC: 0.9545954595459546
Average_precision: 0.9541994473779806
```

As Yellowbrick handles all these computational details internally (and transparently), it does not suffer from the mistake in the manual scikit-learn procedure made here.

---

Notice that, in the binary case (as here), you can (and should) make your plots less cluttered with the `binary=True` argument:

```
viz3 = ROCAUC(LogisticRegression(random_state=seed), binary=True) # similarly for the PrecisionRecall curve
```

and that, contrary to what one migh expect intuitively, for the binary case at least, the `score` method of `ROCAUC` will **not** return the AUC, but the accuracy, as specified in the [docs](https://www.scikit-yb.org/en/latest/api/classifier/rocauc.html#yellowbrick.classifier.rocauc.ROCAUC.score):

```
viz3.score(X_test, y_test)
# 0.88

# verify this is the accuracy:

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, clf_lr.predict(X_test))
# 0.88
```